# How do I translate this query from MS Access into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

How do I translate this into SQL Server:

```
select 
-Sum((12=[GroupNum])*[BoardStatus]) AS G12
FROM 
 QryAllBoardsByPacketIDs 
INNER JOIN 
 tBsReportGroups 
  ON QryAllBoardsByPacketIDs.NominalLengthMetric=tBsReportGroups.NomLenMet
GROUP BY 
 QryAllBoardsByPacketIDs.ParentPacketID, 
 QryAllBoardsByPacketIDs.GradeID, 
 QryAllBoardsByPacketIDs.NominalWidthMetric,   
 QryAllBoardsByPacketIDs.NominalThicknessMetric;
```

Kind regards,

Martin

Comment: I think you need to explain what this part does `(12=[GroupNum])*[BoardStatus]`. It looks like you are summing all rows where `GroupNum` is `12`. If that is a case then you could use `sum(BoardStatus)` and add a where clause `where GroupNum = 12`.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure I follow as I rarely use Access, but I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT -SUM(
   CASE WHEN 12=[GroupNum] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
   * [BoardStatus]
   ) AS G12
[...]
```

CASE...WHEN is the inline "if" of T-SQL.

Comment: I would like to ask if the -SUM has any translation

Comment: @user1124937: Try replacing `-sum((12=[GroupNum])*` with `sum(case when GroupNum = 12 then 1 else 0 end *`

Answer (score 1):

Cheers for that, why MS Access has to be different to everything else?  Mmm.  I got to the bottom of it like you said using :

```
G1 = SUM(CASE WHEN GroupNum = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)*BoardStatus,
G2 = SUM(CASE WHEN GroupNum = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)*BoardStatus,
.....
G10 = SUM(CASE WHEN GroupNum = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)*BoardStatus,
G11 = SUM(CASE WHEN GroupNum = 11 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)*BoardStatus,
G12 = SUM(CASE WHEN GroupNum = 12 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)*BoardStatus
```

It was the - before the sum that threw me, as the output is not negative.  Regards,

Martin